# setting the titlestring in vimrc to simply be the filename being edited

Tags: bash, shell, vim

currently I have the title set using the simple `set title` in my vimrc and it gives me something like `program.py ~/path/to/program.py - VIM`

This is... okay... but kind of annoying. Is there a way to set it to simply be something along `program.py` plain and simple? Perhaps using `titlestring`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want the filename in the title:

```
:set titlestring=%t
```

For other possibilities, look at:

```
:help titlestring
```

which will lead you to:

```
:help statusline
```

for the list of `%` codes.

Comment: thank you good sir, this was successful. Now it only displays what I want to see, just how I want it